# Adding standard error bars to a bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add standard error bars to my bar plot but i can't quite work it out!

This is my bar plot code:

```
ggplot(data = pdiv, aes(x = Area, y = Diversity, fill = Area)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("Area") +
  ylab("Simpson's Diversity Index score") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    breaks = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
    values = c("indianred1", "mediumorchid3", "lightgreen", "lightblue")
  )
```

I've tried calculating means and then doing it manually but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: We can't run your code without your data, and we can't see your plot. Could you please share a little bit of sample data? `dput(pdiv[1:10, ])` will give copy/pasteable R code to create the first 10 rows of your `pdiv` data. Also please show your best attempt... normally we use `geom_errorbar()` [as in this R Graph Gallery example](https://r-graph-gallery.com/4-barplot-with-error-bar.html). Have you tried that?